# How to get the overridden keys value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Map<String,String> mapp=new HashMap<>();
mapp.put("1", "abc");
mapp.put("1", "def");

System.out.println(mapp.size());
System.out.println(mapp.get("1"));
System.out.println(mapp);
```

o/p

```
1
def
{1=def}
```

How to get 'abc' value and wheather its present in the map as size is 1.

Can this be a case of hash collision, as the key is same can it produce same hashcode and store in the same index?

Comment: It's gone you can not get it.

Comment: Only when you use `put` method, you can get the value which has been replaced by new one, after that statement, the value is not accessible unless you store it in separate variable.

Comment: You are overwriting the mapped value for that key, so why are you expecting to be able to somehow retain the overwritten value? What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps a Map is not what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can this be a case of hash collision, as the key is same can it produce same hashcode and store in the same index.

Comment: It's nothing to do with hash collision. The same thing can be seen if you use a TreeMap. Or any other kind of map. Each key maps to one value. And every key in a map is unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapp.put("1", "def");` would return the previous value - "abc" - of the key "1".

You can see it with:

```
System.out.println(mapp.put("1", "def"));
```

Afterwards, there's no way to obtain the original value of the "1" key, since it has been overwritten.

This is specified in the Javadoc of `put`:

> **V java.util.Map.put(K key, V value)**
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value**. (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)
>
> **Returns:**
>
> **the previous value associated with key**, or null if there was no mapping for key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have clobbered a key's value in a hashmap, that value is for all intents and purposes gone.  If you have a need to keep track of multiple values associated with a key, then consider using a map of some sort of collection:

Use a map of lists:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapp = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
mapp.put("1", list);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.